# Having Issue on Loading Pre-loader only From External entery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom pre-loader on my `index.php` as

```
<div id="page-mask">
    <div class="mask-spinner">
      <div class="rect1"></div>
      <div class="rect2"></div>
      <div class="rect3"></div>
      <div class="rect4"></div>
      <div class="rect5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery as:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $("#page-mask .mask-spinner").delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
    $("#page-mask").delay(1500).slideUp(600);
  });
});
```

which is working perfectly when users enter the site like `www.domain.com` but the pre-loader also is running when user get back to `Home` through the navigation a well. for example if user is in `Portfolio` page or `Contact` page and what to back to `home` through navigation the pre-loader runs again! which is not required now.

Can you please let me know how I can run the jquery only if users coming to home page through external links?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question is answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34171389/1984039) by me where user wanted to run a script once per visit.

You can also check `document.referrer` if it is of the same domain or not before running a specific script

```
if ( document.referrer != location.hostname )
{
  //run the script here
}
```

you can also check if the one contains the another like

```
if ( document.referrer.indexOf( location.hostname ) == -1 || location.hostname.indexOf( document.referrer) == -1 ) 
{
  //run the script here
}
```

this way you will be able to make out whether you are navigating within the same site or coming from outside.

Comment: Thanks gurvinder372, I tried both methods but none of them worked! still same running!

Comment: @Behseini can you share what you have tried http://jsfiddle.net ? more precisely what is the output of `document.referrer` and `location.hostname`?

Comment: @Behseini i didn't get your answer. Can you please share the info I had asked?

Comment: sure but I am not sure what do you mean by output of `document.referrer` and `location.hostname`?

Comment: @Behseini run these commands on your browser's console and share the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100633/discussion-between-behseini-and-gurvinder372).